# Switching from one tty to another terminates X server

Tags: tty, xserver

I would like to login two users to my pc. One user is on TTY6 and the other is on TTY7. I login the second user in tty6 and type startx to start desktop environment.

Whenever I switch to the default one (TTY7), after switching back to tty6 ,I cannot see the desktop environment anymore. I need to type startx again. Here is the log I got from Xorg log:

http://pastebin.kde.org/pt69bk9sv

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/416825/how-to-quick-switch-between-desktop-environments-in-the-running-desktop-session/419420#419420 . try with `export DISPLAY=localhost:1`