# Start another GUI on different TTY

Tags: lightdm, gui, services, tty

For some reason I want to have 2 GUIs open at different TTYs.

the commands

```
sudo service lightdm stop/start
```

will stop/create a new GUI at TTY7. but how can I do the same at different TTYs or redirect its output?

Comment: probably not possible without some serious coding. see lightdm.conf. tty7 is hardcoded here (and in other places). edit; have a look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX

Comment: as @Rinzwind said it is not possible, in the same user environment. But you can check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/416825/how-to-quick-switch-between-desktop-environments-in-the-running-desktop-session) question, may be one of answers will fits you

Comment: it used to be possible @c0rp (I used to change /etc/inittab and have kde on tty8 and gdm on tty7) lightdm though seems to be very light(as the same stated) multiseat might work but it will take some configurationing

Comment: interesting topic: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143902&page=3

Comment: @Rinzwind Here the correct sequence is login **as another user** in a VT and then  `startx -- :1`. In my Ubuntu Gnome / gdm setup will start a new server on tty8. Tested just now. Probably the exact effect  is dependent on the xinit scripts, so could be different between gdm , ligthdm and whatnot.

Answer (score 5):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>(Desired Function key) this way you will switch
   to another tty
2. After logging in to this console (Entering username    and password)
   run this command: **`tty`** this will show you the number    of current
   tty.
3. To start Xserver also run this command (place value of returned tty number in place of n)
   and for your knowledge `:2` is number of the `$DISPLAY` instance.

   ```
   startx -display :2 -- :2 vtn &
   ```

   Like I'm doing this for tty1 here:

   ```
   startx -display :2 -- :2 vt1 &
   ```

   at this point you can launch your graphical application
   though you can use this alternative instead of previous command:

   ```
   xinit session -- :1 -xf86config config.conf
   ```
4. Next step is running a graphical program in TTYn:(like VirtualBox in
   Virtual terminal n)

   Start a detached X server (again replace n with tty number like:vt1):

   ```
   sudo X -quiet -nolisten tcp -noreset :4 vtn
   ```
5. Run wathever application you want like VirtualBox, for example:

   ```
   DISPLAY=:4 virtualbox &
   ```

**Note**: Don't forget the you should enter all these commands just in dedicated tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and not in your graphical console.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Warning: closing down X with Ctrl+Alt+Backspace is global, not only for the foreground tty.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested the above answer in response to jasonszhao's comment that it does not work.  Using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS there were no issues with the commands.

**Note:**

```
sudo X -quiet -nolisten tcp -noreset :4 vtn
```

"n" in "vt**N** is the tty number you want to run the graphical display.  So in  my case I ran

```
sudo X -quiet -nolisten tcp -noreset :4 vt8
```

to start another X session on tty8 and then I used

```
DISPLAY=:4 virtualbox &
```

to start the program I wanted to run on DISPLAY:4.

Comment: 1st command has to be faulty: 1 " can never be correct. And I end up with a black screen on tty8 with the last 2 commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just Goto another `tty` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> but you can return to Ubuntu default GUI using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

I am using DDE in my case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
then I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
startx
```

will start a fresh GUI

Comment: It starts and immediately exists the X Session. How to run it and keep it running?