# Switching Window Manager without Logging-out

Tags: bash, xfce, window-manager, awesome

I run both XFCE's `xfwm` and `awesome`. I'm usually in `awesome` but I occasionally have to run some applications that don't play nicely at all with tiling window managers.

I'm looking for a way to switch between window managers while remaining in the same session, with all apps and windows open. Can this easily be achieved with a couple of commands or a `bash` script?

I currently have to log out and select a different WM at the login screen, which of course means saving everything and loosing all my open windows.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution for WM binding in the same session.

```
man dm-tool
```

Details can be found in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416825/switch-between-desktop-environments-instantly-within-the-running-desktop-session) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (put in the bash script and You can even run it via keyboard shortcuts - just assign proper scripts in XFCE and Awesome) :

To switch to Awesome:

```
killall xfwm4 && awesome &
```

To switch to XFCE:

```
killall awesome && xfwm4 &
```