How to add desktop tty's?
I noticed that if I click Ctrl+Alt+F2, I get another TTY with a desktop on Ubuntu 22.06. However, if I go to Ctrl+Alt+F3, I get a CLI login on tty3.
How could I add desktops to different ttys? Not more windows or users, but displays. What configuration file if any should I edit?
I would like to add desktops to tty3 and tty4. I know one way to do this is to run startx but I would like to have login desktops like we see on other pages.

When you login which desktop will you login to?

I usually log into tty1, but I sometimes use tty2. I would like 2 more to be able to access.

Do you want to login to the same session or to different environment, let's say KDE on tty1 and Gnome on tty2?

Usually I can do that just by using the "switch user" option in the logout menu, and then just log in again.  You could have a separate session on each virtual console all logged in as the same user.  If this isn't what you want, add the difference to your question.

@NumberFile Would you try mango's answer here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/417535/26246 it may still working. Please, read my comment there

This question is similar to: Switch between desktop environments instantly within the running desktop session. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
